# .htacces 301 redirect from certain links to main site

Tags: .htaccess

What I'm trying to achieve is redirect all links starting with:

```
    http://example.com/en/(...)
```

to this page

```
    http://example.com
```

How would I achieve that using .htaccess 301 redirection?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/(.*)$ /$1
```